# How do I hide the entire parent (top) level in superfish?

Tags: navigation

Using the [Superfish](https://drupal.org/project/superfish) module, I need to show just the second level and below. That means, hide the entire first (parent) level and only show the child level based on the current page.

Is this possible?

I tried editing the Superfish block and changing the menu depth, but it doesn't allow me to choose the depth to exclude above it.

Comment: If you want anything more than workarounds, it should rather be feature request in issue queue. Anyway, why don't just hide top level with CSS? I guess no harm in it being there if nobody sees it anyway, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this would be with CSS.

What you want to do is set all menu items to be hidden via `display: none;`, and then override that property for child items.

Something like this (will need to be adapted to your specific DOM/selectors):

```
.my-nav ul {
  display: none;
}

  .my-nav ul ul {
    display: block;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Menu block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module allows you to choose which level to show, and how deep.

It won't integrate with superfish module, but allows you to build the submenus you're looking for. Moreover, those submenus may be themed to use basic superfish:

```
function THEMENAME_menu_tree__menu_block__1($variables) {
    return '<ul class="menu sf-menu">'. $variables['tree'] .'</ul>';
}
```

`1` in the function name is the delta of the custom menu_block created.

Although posible, there's no straight way to leverage advanced superfish configuration / styling within a menu_block: APIs are not isolated enough as to theme a menu_block with a complex superfish style in a few of lines.

Just note also that a closer integration of both modules is feasible (I think of superfish using menu_block API).

So, although incomplete, I think menu_block + superfish is the best alternative.

Comment: I need this to be done with superfish (as per my orginal post), not menu block.

Comment: You could use menublock and then apply Superfish by adding the appropriate classes to the generated menu. You don't have to use the Superfish module to use Superfish effects.

Comment: Interesting. What class does the superfish js latch onto?

Comment: I further thought this will not work as the superfish module provides a ton of extra settings on the block settings that I need to leverage. This approach is not going to work.

Comment: Sorry for the first version of my response, I just pointed out a helpful piece to approach the solution, but didn't explained. I've edited my response to add more details.